# facebook open graph post sotry

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

[image: image 1]
I am trying to achieve this goal in third image using Facebook open graph.I am done with first line in first image.But not knows how to post with friends like in second image.If some knows about it.Help me.

[image: image 2]

[image: image 3]

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a facebook feature. If it observes many people doing same action, it combines them. e.g. *Mr A and 10 others shared a link.*

So if you succeed in first step, facebook will do the rest.